# matlab coding for mean value of one row

Tags: matlab, average

I need matlab coding for measuring mean value of one row in a matrix of 180 by 50 rows and columns. Each time the number of row in a matrix needs to be updated to get mean value of next row (like `new_row=1:1:180`). Kindly respond as soon as possible

Comment: What have you tried so far? Very few people are going to be receptive to writing code FOR you, stackoverflow is for helping to write code WITH you.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`mean()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html).

```
mean(A,2)
```

This will give you the means of each row of matrix A.

P.S.: If you already save one row in a vector, say `new_row`, you can simply use:

```
mean(new_row)
```

Comment: It is always recommended to use the "neat" function MATLAB provides as exactly as possible. In a code I maintain we had `y = mean(x.').'` - until it fell on my feet earlier this week because there was only one row in a sample dataset. Only then I learned about the 2nd argument of this function.

Comment: @glglgl I can still get the correct result for your code for a row vector. I don't quite get your idea. Can you explain more?

Comment: Actually i am looking for 180 values of mean of 180 rows to create radiation pattern for 180 degrees. so i have 180 by 50 rows and column matrix. I am using following command:

"Readings_AngleWise" is 180by50 matrix
DegreeSpacing=2;
for     i = 1:1:180
    Degree(i) = mean(Readings_AngleWise,2)
    
    end
mean(Degree(i))
Degree(i)

Is this command correct? or you suggest me

Comment: @user3338364 Don't need a loop. You can simply use `mean(Readings_AngleWise, 2)`. It will give you all 180 means.

Comment: I solved this problem, thanks.

Comment: But i need a bit more help. I want to get 2d radiation pattern in matlab. I am using "polar" command but it says that "THETA and RHO must be of same size". However THETA and RHo values are same i.e. 180

Comment: @herohuyongtao Could as well have been the `isnan()` function, don't remember. But I needed the version which operates on one certain dimension, which essentially returns a vector of the same shape as the orogonal one and not only one value.